# ¿Como crear una llave compuesta en MVC?

Tags: c#, mvc

Buen dia
tengo un Modelo llamado **city**

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must contain less than {1} characters.")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int IdDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

**DataContext**

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasIndex(t => t.Name)
            .IsUnique();
    }
```

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCity(City city)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Department department = await _context.Departments
            .Include(d => d.Cities)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == city.IdDepartment);
        if (department == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            city.Id = 0;
            department.Cities.Add(city);
            _context.Update(department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction($"{nameof(DetailsDepartment)}/{department.Id}");

        }
        catch (DbUpdateException dbUpdateException)
        {
            if (dbUpdateException.InnerException.Message.Contains("duplicate"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "There are a record with the same name.");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, dbUpdateException.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, exception.Message);
        }
    }

    return View(city);
}
```

Hasta aqui todo me funciona bien, si yo intento grabar un mismos Nombre de ciudad 2 veces me marca el mensaje "There are a record with the same name."

el problema es que ahora, me topo con que 2 departamentos, o Estados, Pueden Tener el Mismo nombre de ciudad, por lo que me gustaria que la llave primaria, fuera una llave compuesta... en sql no tengo problemas para hacerlo, pero la duda es , como crearia una llave compuesta desde el Codigo, asi como Hice la llave Primaria en el **DataContext** ... espero que me puedan apoyar a resolver la duda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje estás programando? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar a la pregunta la etiqueta correspondiente al mismo.

Comment: puedes colocar el [key] public int Id { get; set; } en tu clase City, y como tienes la relacion City - Department?